# sudo apt install net-tools

Tags: apt

I am very new to the Ubuntu.I was trying to run command (attached) and got an error.
Could you please help me getting this resolved.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to access other websites on this device? The mirror might be down. You may just need to wait and try again. FYI: it can be difficult to read and work with images of text.  Instead of uploading pictures of your terminal, please copy/paste and use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) for formatting.

Comment: Welcome to AU. Please provide details at the very least of your Ubuntu version - and ideally hardware too. It's hard to help you without some details.

Comment: Please provide the output of: `nslookup in.archive.ubuntu.com` and `nslookup archive.ubuntu.com` - it's always a good idea to see if you can resolve a given domain with `nslookup`.

Comment: Also it is best to include text in the body of the question, not pictures of it.

Comment: HI Nmath,I am not able to use any website in this.I am learning Linux where i used VM Virtualbox and ubuntu.I just created a machine and practicing few codes.I think what you asked,could be a potential problem, would you suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: Hi Will, Thank you. Answer for your query is:- ubuntu 18.04.6,  Release: 18.04,  Codename:- bionic

Comment: Hi Artur, I have added a screenshot of the command you mentioned and attach screenshot as result can not be copied outside virtualbox.please refer the question and you will find screenshot.